# SQL Query given a select Query searching a varchar xml that may not be well formed

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have two queries that both search a table that has a column of varchars that  could be a potentially invalid xml. I need to match the results of two select queries that produce a value generated from doing a substring to find the node in the message xml.

1. Is a large table that has a MessageId value from the row's message xml given a known NCPDPID.

   ```
   select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11, charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as SQLmessageID from messagelog m where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%'
   ```
2. Returns a smaller table when given the MessageID values from the query above.

   ```
   select substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20, charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, * from messagelog r where message like '%<RelatesToMessageID>z4480</RelatesToMessageID>%'
   ```
3. Get the Primary Keys of the 2nd query.

I was working on a join like this. But the select queries above do not work with the join syntax.

```
  select messageLogId from (select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11, charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as SQLmessageID from messagelog m where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%')

    join ( select substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20, charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, * from messagelog r 
where message like '%<RelatesToMessageID>z4480</RelatesToMessageID>%') 

on SQLmessageID = SQLRelatesMessageID
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. But the first Query returns a column of values that needs to be re-queried with strings appended on it.

```
 select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11, charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as SQLmessageID from messagelog m where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%'

  (select substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20, charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, * from messagelog r  where message like ('%<RelatesToMessageID>' + SQLmessageID +'</RelatesToMessageID>%') )
```

Comment: SQL Server Manager 2012

Comment: How do you do the join query, because it sounds like you have incorrect syntax?

Comment: I would take the first two Select statements and replace the "1st select" and "2nd select" in the 3rd join query.

Comment: What does "do not work" mean? Are you getting the wrong results? No results? An error message? If an error message, then what is it? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, the syntax is not working if I want to do a join query on JOIN. Says it is expecting AS or ID. The m.messagelog = r.messagelog is complaining that the multi-part identifier cant be bound. I thought I was asking a general question trying to get the answer to: how do I re-query given a subquery.

Comment: Post real query instead of pseudo-code.